# Azure: Auto upgrade failed. 'pypi'

Tags: azure

When running any azure commands e.g. `az login` I'm running into this error message `Auto upgrade failed. 'pypi'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [this conversation on a GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/20473#issuecomment-979594791) it seems that auto-upgrade isn't actively maintained.

[image]

To resolve the error find the `.azure/config` file [On mac the path could be `~/.azure/config`]

```
[auto-upgrade]
enable = no
```

Comment: Is disabling the config actually resolved the issue, or is it just masking the error message? It seems that's it preferable that the auto update will be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If using Azure CLI from Windows:

The config is in `C:\Users\username\.azure`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-configuration

Answer (score 0):

To check current setting:

```
az config get auto-upgrade
```

To disable it:

```
az config set auto-upgrade.enable=no
```